# Does every hyperbolic space admit a vertex-transitive 'grid'?

Tags: manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

This isn't exactly a question about tiling. It's closely related enough that I though the tag was justified but it's not closely related enough that I can figure out how to apply the existing literature to this question.

Let $\mathbf{H}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space with its standard Riemannian metric. Does there always exist a set $X\subseteq \mathbf{H}^n$ with the following properties?

- $X$ is uniformly discrete, i.e. there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for any distinct $x,y\in X$, $d(x,y) > \varepsilon$.
- $X$ uniformly covers $\mathbf{H}^n$, i.e. there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x\in \mathbf{H}^n$ there is a $y\in X$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta$.
- $X$ is vertex-transitive, i.e. for any $x,y\in X$ there is a isometry $f:\mathbf{H}^n\rightarrow \mathbf{H}^n$ such that $y=f(x)$ and $f(X)=X$.

The only relevant result I have found is on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_polytopes_and_compounds) Wikipedia article, which mentions that "There are no compact regular tessellations of hyperbolic space of dimension 5 or higher and no paracompact regular tessellations in hyperbolic space of dimension 6 or higher." But it seems like that's requiring more regularity than I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired set $X \subset \mathbb H^n$ can be constructed if you have a subgroup $\Gamma$ of the isometry group $\text{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$ which satisfies the following properties:

1. ($\Gamma$ is discrete) For each $x \in \mathbb H^n$ the orbit $\Gamma \cdot x = \{\gamma(x) \mid \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb H^n$
2. ($\Gamma$ is cocompact) There exists a compact set $D \subset \mathbb H^n$ such that $\Gamma \cdot D = \{\gamma(x) \mid \gamma \in \Gamma, x \in D\}$ is equal to the whole of $\mathbb H^n$.

Once you have that, then for your set $X$ you can simply take an orbit $X = \Gamma \cdot x$, for any $x \in \mathbb H^n$.

A discrete cocompact subgroup of $\text{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$ is also called a *cocompact lattice* in $\text{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$ (there are also noncocompact lattices, but I won't go into that).

Cocompact lattices can be constructed in $\text{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$ for every $n$, but the constructions in high dimensions are not easy. I notice that the wikipedia pages don't seem to contain too much information about constructions, more just about the general theory. One exception is [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)#Lattices_in_semisimple_Lie_groups) although the [existence statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)#Arithmetic_groups_and_existence_of_lattices) is set in a very general context. The connection on that page with hyperbolic space is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup)#Rank_1_versus_higher_rank) where they discuss $SO(n,1)$, which is matrix representation of $\text{Isom}(\mathbb H^n)$.

Comment: A standard example of a uniform arithmetic lattice is the stabilizer of the quadratic form $x_1^2+...+x_n^2 -\sqrt{k}x_{n+1}^2$ in $GL(n+1, Z[\sqrt{k}])$ where $k$ is any natural number which is not a square, e.g. $k=2$. A good reference is http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/papers/Book.pdf, page 95.